# Field of a model upadated by another model django

Tags: django, signals, models

I have a model lets say customer. And i want to add a field to that customer lets say next_meeting. It will be a datetime field, and will have the date of the next meeting with the customer. I also have a Meeting model that has a date field of type datetimeField again. So they look something like that.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    ....fields....
    next_meeting = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


class Meeting(models.Model):
    ....fields....
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='meetings')
```

I want the customer.next_meeting field to contain the most recent date of all the next meetings. So I was thinking doing a post save signal that would take the date of the meeting, and

```
1. Check if customer.next_meeting is null (first meeting). If null set next_meeting to meeting.date
2. If not null check if meeting.date < customer.next_meeting. If true update customer.next_meeting
```

The same must be done for the post delete signal(if a meeting is deleted).

```
1. get the most recent meeting after current date for customer using order_by('date')[0]
2. If meeting: update the next_meeting field, else(no meetings) leave blank.
```

Is this correct way to do this. It sounds a bit too "expensive" if you have a lot of meetings for a customer database side expensive. Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you design your database structure you should make sure you don't repeat the same information in multiple places - i.e. that the database in normalized. Get rid of the `next_meeting` field all together, you can still get the information with the right query:

Get the most recent meeting for customer with id `customer_id`:

```
Meeting.objects.filter(customer=customer_id).order_by('date').first()
```

Add most recent meeting date to every user in a queryset:

```
Customer.objects.annotate(next_meeting=Min('meeting__date'))
```

This assumes there are no past meetings in the database - because your solution also required that is the case. If it is not you would obviously need one more filter, to filter out meetings in the past.

Comment: Oh ty very much. So it doesn't need to be stored in the db. But what if users check the customer page more often than meetings are updated. Isn't that query(the meeting one you wrote) more expensive than to have it stored in db?

Comment: You should design your db to be normalized, and then selectively demoralize or cache it when (or rather "if"!) you hit real life performance issues. When that day comes there are multiple third party packages for caching/denormalizing, like cache machine, johny cache and django-denorm.

Comment: annotate won't add a field right?Only create one for as long as the query exists?Something like that?